# Forge viewer markups EVENT_EDITMODE_ENTER

Tags: reactjs, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to load my markups string from a cloud database using `React` the following code

```js
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!viewer.current) {
      return;
    }
    const handleMarkupsFinished = (ext: any) => {
      if (ext.type === "EVENT_EDITMODE_ENTER") {
        ext.target?.loadMarkups(`${markupsData?.markupsString}`, "layer_1");
        ext.target?.enterEditMode("layer_1");
        ext.target?.leaveEditMode();
      }
    };
    viewer.current
      .loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore")
      .then((ext: any) => {
        ext.addEventListener(
          //@ts-ignore
          Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core.EVENT_EDITMODE_ENTER,
          handleMarkupsFinished
        );
      });

    return () => {
      viewer?.current
        ?.loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore")
        .then((ext: any) => {
          ext.addEventListener(
            //@ts-ignore
            Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core.EVENT_EDITMODE_ENTER,
            handleMarkupsFinished
          );
        });
    };
  }, [viewer.current]);
```

My issue the component keep re-rendering when i am using `ext.target?.leaveEditMode()`
general speaking i am not sure if this is the best practice to load the markups.

---

**Update:**

I am doing this is way and it works great, the only problem that i can't load the last edit markups, if I don't reload the viewer, even i am loading the last saved edit markups string from my db it keep show the first markups string!

```
React.useEffect(() => {
viewer?.current?.addEventListener(
  Autodesk.Viewing.TOOL_CHANGE_EVENT,
  async (x) => {
    const extension = (await viewer?.current?.loadExtension(
      "Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore"
    )) as any;

    if (x.active && x.toolName === "markups.core" && markupsData?.id) {
      await extension?.leaveEditMode();
      //@ts-ignore
      await extension.loadMarkups(
        `${markupsData?.markupsString}`,
        "layer_1"
      );
      await extension.enterEditMode("layer_1");
      // await extension.show(); //it loads the markups even without 'await extension.show()'
    }
  }
);
```

}, [markupsDataIsSuccess]);

[image]

Comment: It looks like a potential endless loop - you have an event handler for the `EVENT_EDITMODE_ENTER` event, and inside the handler you're calling `enterEditMode`. If what you're trying to do is loading markups as soon as the markup extension is activated, you'll probably need to use a different type of event.

Answer (score 1):

If you're attempting to activate the Markups extension, and immediately populate it with existing markups, I'd suggest doing it the following way:

```js
async function activateMarkups(viewer, markups) {
    const ext = await viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore');
    ext.show();
    ext.loadMarkups(markups, 'my-layer');
    ext.enterEditMode('my-layer');
}
```

But again, make sure that this helper function is **not** called within an event handler for the `Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core.EVENT_EDITMODE_ENTER` event as that could result in an endless loop.

EDIT:

Following up on your question edit, please note that you can only load markups into a "fresh" layer. In your code snippet it looks like you're trying to load markups into the same layer ("layer_1") repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks Petr, please check the edit version above.